# "Don't teach somebody to do bad things" - is there any expressions in English?

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice

In Russian there's a sort of expressions like "Не учи его/ee плохому". Literally, "Do not teach him/her to do bad things", usually used, when somebody gives an advice, that could be harmful for the person, who targeted with advice.

Is there any expressions for this in English, or this should be translated as is?

Comment: If a programmer implements advice without understanding it properly, then that can be '[cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the context of the original Russian expression, so this is just a shot in the dark:

Don't set a bad example.

Don't lead him|her astray.

Comment: Right. "Leading them astray" sounds just like what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @AE: yes, looks like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with stronger impilcations but I think that "*[be the ruin of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ruin) of someone or something*" may convey the idea you are suggesting:

> - the cause of failure or destruction;  Your bad judgment will be the ruin of this company! The greedy politicians were the ruin of the old empire.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually a current expression but it seems to fit:

> "Set a good example and your peers will follow"

This is a current saying:

> "Do as I say, not as I do"